# Port COM Handling in C++ cause Watchdog Violation

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, port, watchdog

I'm writing an application for handling communication with the device by COM port.
For it I use `ReadFile()` from `<windows.h>`, as I had some problems with synchronous use, I tried overlapped implementation from http://www.egmont.com.pl/addi-data/instrukcje/standard_driver.pdf
And from what I understand for constant reading (to not lose any data sent by device), I need to call that reading func in a separate thread in infinite `while()` - I created some class for handling that and it's working perfectly, but after some random amount of time it's causing bluescreen **DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION** unfortunately, I can't tell any specific event that may cause this :(

#edit1
I should add that's if I use some other program for COM communication, like Termite or TerraTerm it's working with no problems.

*PortHandling.cpp* (basically copy of that's overlapped implementation) :

```
#define OVERLAPPED_READ_TIMEOUT 1
PortHandling::PortHandling()
{
    this->portHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    this->done = false;
    this->portSelected = "";
    this->baudRate = 0;
}

void PortHandling::ClearPort()
{
    if (this->done)
    {
        this->done = false;
        PurgeComm(this->portHandle, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
        CloseHandle(this->portHandle);
        std::cout << "[E] Disconnected from port " << this->portSelected << std::endl;
    }
}

bool PortHandling::SetPortProp(std::string portName, int baudRate, int maxReadSize, int maxWriteSize)
{
    this->portSelected = portName;
    this->portHandle = CreateFileA(("\\\\.\\" + this->portSelected).c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
    if (this->portHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "[E] Connecting to port failed - Port occupied" << std::endl;
        this->portSelected = "";
        return false;
    }

    SetupComm(this->portHandle, maxReadSize, maxWriteSize); // The size of input buffer and output buffer
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeOuts;
    timeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 3; //Set read timeout
    timeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 3;
    timeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0; // Set write timeout
    timeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    SetCommTimeouts(this->portHandle, &timeOuts); // Set timeout

    DCB dcb;
    GetCommState(this->portHandle, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = baudRate;               /* Baudrate at which running       */
    dcb.fBinary = 1;                       /* Binary Mode (skip EOF check)    */
    dcb.fParity = 0;                       /* Enable parity checking          */
    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = 0;                  /* CTS handshaking on output       */
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = 0;                  /* DSR handshaking on output       */
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;  /* DTR Flow control                */
    dcb.fDsrSensitivity = 0;               /* DSR Sensitivity                 */
    dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = 1;             /* Continue TX when Xoff sent      */
    dcb.fOutX = 0;                         /* Enable output X-ON/X-OFF        */
    dcb.fInX = 0;                          /* Enable input X-ON/X-OFF         */
    dcb.fErrorChar = 1;                    /* Enable Err Replacement          */
    dcb.fNull = 1;                         /* Enable Null stripping           */
    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; /* Rts Flow control                */
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;                      /* Number of bits/byte, 4-8        */
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;                 /* 0-4 = None,Odd,Even,Mark,Space  */
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;             /* 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2               */
    dcb.XonChar;                           /* Tx and Rx X-ON character        */
    dcb.XoffChar;                          /* Tx and Rx X-OFF character       */
    dcb.ErrorChar;                         /* Error replacement char          */
    dcb.EofChar;                           /* End of Input character          */
    dcb.EvtChar;                           /* Received Event character        */

    SetCommState(this->portHandle, &dcb);
    PurgeComm(this->portHandle, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);

    this->done = true;
    std::cout << "[I] Connecting to port " << this->portSelected << " succeeded" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

//@brief
//param size    - Maximal read size, may be shorter if read is waiting for longer than set timeout (10ms)
//param buffer  - Buffer into witch read data is saved
//param onRead  - Function that is called on succesfull read
DWORD PortHandling::ReadFromPort(int size, char *buffer, std::function<void()> onRead)
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
    OVERLAPPED osReader = {0};

    // Create the overlapped event. Must be closed before exiting to avoid a handle leak.
    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (osReader.hEvent == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "[E] Error in communication, overlapped construction failed" << std::endl;
        return dwRead;
    }

    if (!fWaitingOnRead)
    {
        // Issue read operation.
        if (!ReadFile(this->portHandle, buffer, size, &dwRead, &osReader))
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) // read not delayed?
            {
                std::cout << "[E] Error in communication (read:1)" << std::endl;
            } else
            {
                fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
            }
        } else
        {
            // read completed immediately
        }
    }

    if (fWaitingOnRead)
    {
        dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent, OVERLAPPED_READ_TIMEOUT);
        switch (dwRes)
        {
            // Read completed.
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(this->portHandle, &osReader, &dwRead, FALSE))
            {
                std::cout << "[E] Error in communication (read:2)" << std::endl;
            } else
            {
                // Read completed successfully.
            }
            //  Reset flag so that another opertion can be issued.
            fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
            break;

        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            // Operation isn't complete yet. fWaitingOnRead flag isn't
            // changed since I'll loop back around, and I don't want
            // to issue another read until the first one finishes.
            // This is a good time to do some background work.
            break;

        default:
            // Error in the WaitForSingleObject; abort.
            // This indicates a problem with the OVERLAPPED
            // structure's event handle
            std::cout << "[E] Error in communication, overlapped construction failed" << std::endl;
            return dwRead;
        }
    }
    if (strlen(buffer) > 0)
    {
        onRead();
    }
    return dwRead;
}

//@brief
//param size    - Size of written message
//param buffer  - Buffer from witch data is send
//param onWrite - Function that is called on succesfull write
bool PortHandling::WriteToPort(int size, const char *buffer, std::function<void()> onWrite)
{
    OVERLAPPED osWrite = {0};
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    BOOL fRes = FALSE;

    // Create this writes OVERLAPPED structure hEvent.
    osWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (osWrite.hEvent == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "[E] Error in communication, overlapped construction failed" << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Issue write.
    if (!WriteFile(this->portHandle, buffer, size, &dwWritten, &osWrite))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            // WriteFile failed, but it isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
            std::cout << "[E] Error in communication (write:1)" << std::endl;
            fRes = FALSE;
        } else
        {
            // Write is pending.
            dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);
            switch (dwRes)
            {
                // OVERLAPPED structure's event has been signaled.
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                if (!GetOverlappedResult(this->portHandle, &osWrite, &dwWritten, FALSE))
                {
                    std::cout << "[E] Error in communication (write:2)" << std::endl;
                    fRes = FALSE;
                } else
                {
                    // Write operation completed successfully.
                    fRes = TRUE;
                    onWrite();
                }
                break;
            default:
                // An error has occurred in WaitForSingleObject.
                // This usually indicates a problem with the
                // OVERLAPPED structure's event handle.
                std::cout << "[E] Error in communication (write:3)" << std::endl;
                fRes = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        // WriteFile completed immediately.
        fRes = TRUE;
        onWrite();
    }
    CloseHandle(osWrite.hEvent);
    return fRes;
}
```

My class for handling that,
*PortOperator.cpp*

```
bool PortOperator::Construct(std::string portName, int baudRate, int maxReadSize, int maxWriteSize)
{
    this->portName = portName;
    this->baudRate = baudRate;
    this->maxReadSize = maxReadSize;
    this->maxWriteSize = maxWriteSize;
    this->cRead = new char[maxReadSize];
    memset(cRead, 0, this->maxReadSize);
    this->cWrite = new char[maxWriteSize];
    memset(cWrite, 0, this->maxWriteSize);

    if (this->PortHandler.SetPortProp(portName, baudRate, maxReadSize, maxWriteSize))
    {
        // if connection succesfull, start Reading in the background
        this->Reading = std::thread(&PortOperator::ReadingThread, this);
    } else
    {
        static ftor_DeltaTime reconnect_timeout = ftor_DeltaTime();
        int n = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            // try reconnecting to port each second, max 5 tries
            if (reconnect_timeout(TimeUnits::SECONDS) >= 1)
            {
                n++;
                if (this->PortHandler.SetPortProp(portName, baudRate, maxReadSize, maxWriteSize))
                {
                    // if connection succesfull, start Reading in the background
                    this->Reading = std::thread(&PortOperator::ReadingThread, this);
                    break;
                }
                if (n > 5)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                reconnect_timeout.Reset();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void PortOperator::ReadingThread()
{
    this->notReciving = ftor_DeltaTime();
    char *buffer = new char[this->maxReadSize];
    while (true)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, this->maxReadSize);
        //make sure the thread is stopped when port disconnect
        if (!this->PortHandler.done)
        {
            break;
        }
        this->PortHandler.ReadFromPort(this->maxReadSize, buffer,
                                       [&]() {
                                           //block executed only when there's some data read (not empty)
                                           if (ConsolePreview)
                                           {
                                               std::cout << buffer;
                                           }
                                           mtx_cRead.lock();
                                           strcpy(this->cRead, buffer);
                                           mtx_cRead.unlock();
                                           readFlag = 1;
                                           cv.notify_all();
                                           notReciving.Reset();
                                       });
    }
}

std::string PortOperator::Write(std::string command)
{
    std::mutex mtx_cv;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> write_lck(mtx_cv);
    std::string response = "";
    this->PortHandler.WriteToPort(command.length(), command.c_str(), []() {});
    if (cv.wait_for(write_lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(45)) == std::cv_status::no_timeout)
    {
        response = cRead;
    }
    return response;
}

bool PortOperator::Reconnect()
{
    this->Disconnect();
    return this->Construct(this->portName, this->baudRate, this->maxReadSize, this->maxWriteSize);
}

bool PortOperator::Disconnect()
{
    //first clear port connection to stop thread, and then join
    this->PortHandler.ClearPort();
    if (Reading.joinable())
    {
        Reading.join();
    }
    return true;
}

long long int PortOperator::SilenceTime(TimeUnits t)
{
    return this->notReciving(t);
}

std::vector<std::string> PortOperator::GetPorts()
{
    std::vector<std::string> portsCOM;
    //try connecting with each port to check which are avaiable
    for (int i = 0; i <= 256; i++)
    {
        std::string portName = "COM" + std::to_string(i);
        if (this->CheckPort(portName))
        {
            portsCOM.push_back(portName.c_str());
        }
    }
    //if there's no avaiable port add "-" to vector
    if (portsCOM.size() == 0)
    {
        portsCOM.push_back(" - ");
    }
    return portsCOM;
}

bool PortOperator::CheckPort(std::string portName)
{
    //try connecting with given port
    HANDLE serialHandle;
    serialHandle = CreateFileA(("\\\\.\\" + portName).c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if (serialHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(serialHandle);
    return true;
}
```

I'm not the best programmer, if something hurt your eyes please tell me...
Thanks for your time :D

Comment: Bluescreen?! Which windows version is that? Perhaps try a recent one...

Comment: Windows 10 Home just updated.
Even if there is no bluescreen on LTSC version, it still behaves similarly (jams whole system) and restarts :/

Comment: That's crazy! No program, no matter how buggy, should be able to crash Windows... Can you try a different computer or different COM port (perhaps USB-adapter), maybe it's some driver causing this.

Comment: I tried on different computers and the problem stays the same (the only difference I found is that LTSC version restart without bluescreen), I also plugged in different USBs ports and updated drivers

Comment: Interesting... sure it isn't some device connected to the port that causes this (electromagnetic interference)?

Comment: If I use some other program for COM communication, like Termite or TerraTerm it's working with no problems.

Comment: Hm, can you simulate your device e.g. with an Arduino? Apply some shielding? Use long wires and opto couplers? If your program turns on, say, a big motor running near the PC, it's conceivable that the EMI crashes it. I think that's more likely than a Windows bug. A bug in your application is likely but shouldn't crash Windows...

Comment: It's only some small PCB, and when I tried on different computers I send a program to friends so it's a completely different environment, different PCB, wires, one has a motor with it.. but it's didn't seem to make any difference.

All seem to point to program error :/

Comment: as side note *I need to call that reading func in a separate thread in infinite while()* - this is wrong. asynchronous i/o work need implement in absolute different way. but this of course not reason for bsod. for understand bsod need how minimum look crash dump/stack trace for begin

Comment: One: if you have a dedicated thread for reading, use blocking reads.  Two:  Reading from port is nice, but each successive read should be in a different buffer, and then queued (in a std::queue, for example) for your main thread to consume.  Otherwise, you will lose data.  Three: Have you considered using boost::asio for your apppllcation?  It's easy to use, reliable, and made for this kind of I/O-centric application.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy
**One:**
I would but I don't know how to state condition for that. It should read when there's some data from the port, but it's don't know that unless it read?
**Two:**
Yeah, now I do that in a separate thread cause I need to save it in my window console one way or another, and I don't want to litter my port communication driver with view control. But I should do that, thanks :) 
**Three:**
 I never considered, do you know any example when someone uses that in a similar scenario to mine?